# HDF5 data layer definition for multiple HDF5 files

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I know that Caffe won't let you have HDF5 data layer larger than 2GB.
 I had a large dataset and I split my large dataset into 5 chunks of <2GB. 
I listed the five files in `'train.txt'` file.
 How can I define it in the `"HDF5Data"` layer in my network prototxt file?
 Just listing all of them as top generates an error. 
Any small example for this? 
Thanks!

Cheers

Comment: I have a question: how did you split your data into multiple HDF5 files??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have **text** file `'train.txt'` with the following content

> ```
> /path/to/first.h5
> /path/to/second.h5
> /path/to/third.h5
> /path/to/fourth.h5
> /path/to/fifth.h5
> ```

Then, as `source` of `"HDF5Data"` layer you should give **only** `'train.txt'`:

```
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  # put your "top" here, if you have several - then go ahead
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/train.txt"  # only the list file goes here.
  }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
```

As you can see, the `'/path/to/first.h5'` are not listed explicitly in the `train.prototxt`, only in `train.txt`.